# Does public key cryptography definition require commutativity in algorithms?

Tags: number-theory

This is a question based on digital signatures. I've been writing an essay on public key cryptography and I understand that with RSA you have

$$\operatorname{Decrypt}(\operatorname{Encrypt}(m,p),s) = \operatorname{Encrypt}(\operatorname{Decrypt}(m,s),p) = m \tag{$*$}$$
where $m$ is a message, $p$ the public key and $s$ the private key.

For RSA, $(*)$ holds because of commutativity of multiplication with prime numbers.

My definition for public key cryptography is:

> An *encryption scheme* is deﬁned by the following spaces and algorithms:
>
> - $M$ the space of all possible messages;
> - $C$ the space of all possible ciphertexts;
> - $P$ the space of all possible public keys;
> - $S$ the space of all possible private keys;
> - $\operatorname{KeyGen}$ - an algoirthm that outputs a public key $p \in P$ and a private key $s \in S$;
> - $\operatorname{Encrypt}$ - an algorithm that takes as input $m \in M$ and $p \in P$, and outputs a ciphertext $c \in C$;
> - $\operatorname{Decrypt}$ - an algorithm that takes $c \in C$ and $s \in S$, and outputs m ∈ M.
>
> It is required that $\operatorname{Decrypt}(\operatorname{Encrypt}(m,p),s) = m$
> if $(p,s)$ is a matching key pair.
> It is also required that the fastest known method of ﬁnding $s$ from $p$ is much harder than generating $s$ and $p$.

For signatures and authentication using the private key to sign a message, do I also require that $(*)$ be a condition in my definition?

Thanks to alexwlchan for improving the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your equation to make any sense we must have $M=C$ and this is the case with RSA but not with some other cryptosystems, for example in the [Pallier cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) the ciphertext is twice the size of the plaintext.  In such a system there are multiple possible ciphertexts for the same plaintext and the latter part of the equation $\text{Encrypt}(\text{Decrypt}(m,s),p)=m$, which makes sense by itself with $m \in C$, is not true.

When we do have $M=C$, the equation is true for any cryptosystem, $\text{Decrypt}(\text{Encrypt}(m,p),s)=m$ is enough to show that $\text{Decrypt}(\cdot,s)$ and $\text{Encrypt}(\cdot,p)$ are permutations and inverses of each other.